# Is there any way to execute qemu-agent-command using libvirt-php API?

Tags: php, qemu, kvm, libvirt

There are many tasks which can be done using `qemu-agent-command`. Using `virsh`, we can do that but is there any way to do it using `libvirt-php` API? I could not find any function at [libvirt API reference](http://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html). I don't want to use bash for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use the php API libvirt for an educational project. I encounter a problem to convert image (e.g.: vdi -> qcow2) without using `bash - exec()` method. Since 0.5.2, `libvirt-php` add a feature for execute `qemu-agent-command`.

You should look for this function : [libvirt_domain_qemu_agent_command](http://libvirt.org/php/api-reference.html#libvirt_domain_qemu_agent_command)